# How to run only a single worksheet in an IntellijIDEA Scala project with several worksheets?

Tags: scala, intellij-idea, intellij-plugin

Within a Scala project, I inserted four worksheets in the `src` directory. I realized however that when i run a worksheet, actually every worksheet is runned (I noticed that from my worksheet I can access to the classes of the other worksheets, even if I didn't explicitly run them before). What I would like is to run only the worksheet I opened and not everyone in the same project. How can I do it?

Full bug report here: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/SCL-16496

Comment: Worksheets are independent so that is really strange, how are you running the worksheets?

Comment: @PedroCorreiaLuís Apparently they are not. I turned on "Interactive Mode" so basically everything is checked in real time, and i setted the run type to "Plain". To explicitly trigger the execution of the current worksheet, i simply click on the little green arrow (the run button). Now i've written to the IntelliJ IDEA support, providing step-by-step screenshots which show the problem and i'm waiting for an answer...

Comment: Interective Mode basically runs when you change something in the worksheet, so if you change something in all worksheets they will run at the same time, maybe you did something like that. But well lets see if the Intellij support helps

Comment: @PedroCorreiaLuís I totally forgot to tell you that a member of the support team had verified that my issue is actually a bug! Anyway i don't think it will be ever fixed because it depends on how many upvotes it receives... In the mean time, i found two workarounds. The first is to make separate modules for every worksheet. And the second is to create a sbt project (instead of the standard project of IDEA for scala) and put worksheets directly in the directory src/. Full bug report here: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/SCL-16496

Comment: Oh wow that is some bad luck dude, but I'm happy you found a workaround at least ;) sorry that I couldn't help more.